# Simple binary subtraction with decimals

Tags: arithmetic, binary

so let's say I am trying to subtract 75.442 by 43.646. I have 43.646 = `00101011.1010`, and 75.442 = `01001011.0111` from 2's compliment. I got -75.442 = `10110101.1000`, by flipping all the bits, then add 1.

So I have:

```
 00101011.1010
+10110101.1000
=11100001.0010
```

The sign bit is 0, so it is negative.
but `11100001.0010` = 225.125

While
43.646 - 75.442 = -31.796

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check your calculation:

00101011.1010 + 10110101.1000 = 11100001.0010

Comment: Thanks for catching the error